# Is there any connected-graph example other than the complete graph where Diameter(G) = Radius(G)?

Tags: graph-theory

We know that, for any graph G, Radius(G) ≤ Diameter(G) ⩽ 2*Radius(G). I was wondering whether there is any connected graph other than the complete graph, where Radius(G) = Diameter(G).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for graphs in which every vertex has the same [eccentricity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphEccentricity.html). So, in particular, any vertex-transitive graph (which, informally, "looks the same" from any vertex) would do: one simple example, aside from complete graphs, is the cycle graph $C_n$, for any number of vertices $n \ge 3$.

To find many more examples, you can use the search feature of the [House of Graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org). It doesn't let you directly find graphs with the same diameter and radius but you can, for example, list graphs with radius 2 and diameter 2 (or any other fixed value). One of the smallest non-vertex-transitive graphs I found there in this way is the [house graph](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/1183), and [here](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/25141) is a nice example with radius and diameter both $4$. Both are also shown below:

[image] [image]

---

Actually, there's a sense in which *almost all* graphs have equal diameter and radius. If you pick an $n$-vertex graph by flipping a coin for each of the $\binom n2$ possible edges to see if it's present, then:

- It's very unlikely for a vertex $v$ to have eccentricity $1$ (you'd need all $n-1$ edges out of $v$ to be present, which happens with probability $\frac1{2^{n-1}}$). So the overall probability of having any such vertex is at most $\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$, which is tiny.
- It's also very unlikely that there's no path of length $2$ between two vertices $v,w$: there are $n-2$ possible paths, each of which is present with probability $\frac14$, so the probability is $(\frac34)^{n-2}$. So the overall probability of having any such pair is at most $\binom n2 (\frac34)^{n-2}$, which is also tiny.

Therefore it's overwhelmingly likely, for large $n$, that a graph chosen in this way has both radius and diameter $2$.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Actually for my specific problem, I can ignore a graph of diameter 2. Is it possible to have a graph where radius and diameter is equal and greater than 2 ?

Comment: Yes; the cycle graphs $C_n$ I mentioned have both equal to $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$. Also, a search on House of Graphs for graphs with diameter 3, radius 3, and at most 15 edges produces ten simple examples, a few of which are the cycles.